# When to call the upper hierarchy's function in overriden function? Before or after other code?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

Beginner in C++ so bear with me.

When having a virtual overriden function, when should you call the base one? Should it be this:

```
void Player::onCollision ( Collidable& otherObject )
{
    /* OTHER CODE */
    /* OTHER CODE */

    PhysicalActor::onCollision ( otherObject );
}
```

Or this:

```
void Player::onCollision ( Collidable& otherObject )
{
    PhysicalActor::onCollision ( otherObject );

    /* OTHER CODE */
    /* OTHER CODE */
}
```

Now I don't know if there is actually a set rule for this - whether it should **always** go first or **always** go last, or even inbetween. I've tried googling but I'm not sure what to google as the title took me 5 minutes to write anyway, and I don't think I remember this in any books I've read. I always opt for the second one, because in my head, you should handle the more generic stuff first, then more specific stuff.

Sorry if this is a simple question!

Thanks!

Comment: There's no set rule. Whatever makes sense in your design.

Comment: Depending on what you wanna do ... It's all up to you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was thinking this. Should you aim for something in specific? Is one way generally seen as better coding standards?

Comment: It is completely application specific. It doesn't even have to be before or after, it might be called in the middle as well, like calling a normal function. When you want that base function invoked, just call it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such requirement in the language.  This is an interface design question, and while libraries sometimes do require the base class to be called at certain times, I consider that a poor API.

The best designs place no requirement on the user to call the base version... ever.  This removes any burden on the author of the derived class.  I've heard of this called *contract-free* api design, as there is no agreement that must be accepted in order to override the function.

Typically with such contracts you make your users accept, it's mixing the base class logic with the part that the client overrides.  So instead of:

```
class Base {
//...   
public:

   // ** this version must be called before an override does anything
   virtual void doSomething() {
      prepare(data); 
   }

private:
   Data data;
}
```

This requires that if you override doSomething, you must first call the base version before doing anything.

A better interface would be something like this:

```
class Base {
//...   
public:
   void doSomething() {  // ** NOT virtual
      prepare(data);
      doSomethingHook();
   }
protected:
   virtual void doSomethingHook() { } // default is to do nothing

private:
   Data data;
}
```

This guarantees that anyone calling doSomething() will always get the data prepared before the overridden virtual function is called, and now the virtual logic is moved "off to the side a little" into a hook function that has no ordering responsibility, only the responsibility to do whatever it's supposed to.

Of course, doSomethingHook *might* be pure-virtual, but some hooks are perfectly fine to be left with an empty implementation, since their purpose is to offer the *option* for derived class to customize behavior at certain points.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer and the work around, which I never thought of. I'll most likely use this at some point. +1